# jQueryUI autocomplete returns a 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to create an autocomplete input box that when you click inside to type, loads the autocomplete word list from a database. I have the word list loading fine from the from the database via an AJAX call, but when I pass that to the autocomplete function it starts to return a 404.

I have no idea why the data displays fine in my alert, but won't autocomplete properly?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tags").click(function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'get_players.php', 
            success: function(data){
                alert(data); // This returns the correct string.
                $("#tags").autocomplete({
                    source: data
                });
            }
        });
    });
}); // END Document.ready.
```

UPDATE: data comes back as a string (I think). I want to use this for a football draft program, so data is a list of player titles seperated by commas. Example:

```
'Andy Dalton - QB Bengals', 'Adrian Peterson - RB Vikings', 'Tom Brady - QB Patriots'
```

This is my get_players.php

```
<?php
//Connect to the Database.
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password", "draftboard");

// Check said connection.
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    print "An error has occured."; 
}

// Get all the players.
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM players");

if($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // For each member of the group...
    for($i = 0;  $i < $result->num_rows; $i++)
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo "'" .$row['name'] . " - " . $row['position'] . " " . $row['team']."', ";
    }
    $result->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: What `type` is `data`? Could you post an example of what the ajax call to `get_players.php` returns?

Comment: I updated the question with an example value and my code. Thanks!

Comment: Your `source` should either be a URL passed as a string, an Array of elements, or a function. Is your `source` any of these 3? I suspect that you just pass a string and autocomplete sees it as a URL but can't find that URL. Hence the 404.

Comment: Ok, try using: `source: data.split(",")`.

Comment: AWESOME! Worked like a charm Joe! Thanks so much. If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autocomplete` expects a url, array or function. You're currently passing a string so just use this to covert it into an array:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: data.split(",")
});
```